# When does non-convex nonlinear least squares have local minima?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima, least-squares, non-convex-optimization

I have an inequality constrained non-linear least squares optimization problem which seeks to find the vectors $\bf{\alpha}$ and $\bf\beta$ that minimize the following cost function:

$$F({\bf\alpha,\bf\beta})=\sum^{N-1}_{n=0} \left (  \frac{x_n - {\bf\beta}^T {\bf t}_n}{{\bf \alpha}^T{\bf t}_n} - y_n \right)^2$$

where $x_n$, $y_n$, and ${\bf t}_n$ are all known, and the parameters are subject to the following constraints:

$${\bf \beta}^T{\bf t}_n\in[b_0,b_1]\quad {\bf \alpha}^T{\bf t}_n\in[a_0,a_1]\quad \forall n\in\{0,1,\cdots,N-1\}.$$

In general, this problem is non-convex--even when $\bf\alpha$ and $\bf\beta$ are scalars.  However, it turns out that for the scalar case, there are no local minima (observed by 3-D plotting out the cost function vs the two parameters).

I would like to know under what conditions will this be the case for the more general scenario of **vectors** $\bf\alpha$ and $\bf\beta$.  Assume that the number of unknowns (i.e., the length of $\bf\alpha$ and $\bf\beta$) is much less than the number of observations $N$.

Comment: What's the dimension of $\alpha$ and $\beta$? If greater than $N/2$ I'd expect *many* local minima in general.

Comment: Modified the question to include dimensionality.